# How to align text in Mermaid flowchart node?

Tags: flowchart, mermaid

I would like to align text in a Mermaid flowchart node so the `Thinkpad` and `iPad` will line up. I tried to insert a `\t` before them but they just got rendered as text.

```
flowchart TD
    A[Christmas] -->|Get money| B(Go shopping)
    B --> C{Let me think}
    C -->|One| D["Laptop: Thinkpad\nTablet: iPad"]
    style D text-align:left
    C -->|Two| E[iPhone]
    C -->|Three| F[fa:fa-car Car]
```

[image]

Link to [live editor](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/edit#eyJjb2RlIjoiZmxvd2NoYXJ0IFREXG4gICAgQVtDaHJpc3RtYXNdIC0tPnxHZXQgbW9uZXl8IEIoR28gc2hvcHBpbmcpXG4gICAgQiAtLT4gQ3tMZXQgbWUgdGhpbmt9XG4gICAgQyAtLT58T25lfCBEW1wiTGFwdG9wOiBUaGlua3BhZFxcblRhYmxldDogaVBhZFwiXVxuICAgIHN0eWxlIEQgdGV4dC1hbGlnbjpsZWZ0XG4gICAgQyAtLT58VHdvfCBFW2lQaG9uZV1cbiAgICBDIC0tPnxUaHJlZXwgRltmYTpmYS1jYXIgQ2FyXSIsIm1lcm1haWQiOiJ7XG4gIFwidGhlbWVcIjogXCJkZWZhdWx0XCJcbn0iLCJ1cGRhdGVFZGl0b3IiOmZhbHNlLCJhdXRvU3luYyI6dHJ1ZSwidXBkYXRlRGlhZ3JhbSI6ZmFsc2V9)

Answer (score 8):

I added a unicode space to line it up:

```
flowchart TD
A[Christmas] -->|Get money| B(Go shopping)
B --> C{Let me think}
C -->|One| D["Laptop: Thinkpad\nTablet: iPad"]
style D text-align:left
C -->|Two| E[iPhone]
C -->|Three| F[fa:fa-car Car]
```

[image: Image of Flowchart]

Answer (score 4):

simple way: use space to fill it.

or if you just want to know how to print `tab` try use `&Tab;`

> Be careful! The `graph` does not work; please use the `flowchart` instead of it.

### Example

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/8.14.0/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<h2>Graph</h2>
<i>Do not use <code>graph</code> `\n` not work.</i>
<div class="mermaid">
graph TD
    A --> B["Laptop: Thinkpad\nTablet: iPad"]
</div>

<h2>flowchart</h2>
<div class="mermaid">
flowchart TD
    A --> B["Laptop: Thinkpad\nTablet&Tab;: iPad"] %% use TAB same as `&#9;`
    C --> D["Laptop: Thinkpad\nTablet : iPad"]     %% use space
    style B text-align:left
    style D text-align:left
</div>
```

### Reference

- [charref](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

  - `&Tab;` `&#9;`, `&#9829 ♥` ...
- [Entity codes to escape characters](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=special-characters-that-break-syntax)